# Почему не работает browser api

Tags: javascript, api, браузер

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "name",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "description",
    "icons": {
        "128": "128.png"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["index.js"],
            "css": ["index.css"],
            "run_at": "document_start"
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "storage", "webRequest", "<all_urls>", "scripting", "storage"]
}
```

content.js

```
browser.runtime.sendMessage({
    name: 'Denis',
});
```

background.js

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    console.log(message);
});
```

Делаю cntl+c -> cntl+v [отсюда](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/) - все ровно не работает... Я не знаю что делать уже и как это заставить работать, но `browser.runtime.onMessage` просто не обрабатывает запрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае происходит ошибка действия от обратного.

Чтобы отправить данные в расширение нам нужно слушать событие на прием данных в файле `content.js` (index.js в моем случае), а не отправлять их. Чтобы получить данные в расширении, нам нужно отправить данные на целевую страницу, а не слушать их прием.

Логично было представить это иначе. Нам нужно отправить данные с целевой страницы в расширение - отправляем данные с целевой страницы в расширение:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage()
```

Расширение со своей стороны их прослушивает и получает результат:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener()
```

Проблема в том, что все происходит в точности наоборот, и хотя в документации написано:

> На принимающей стороне необходимо настроить прослушиватель событий
> runtime.onMessage для обработки сообщения. Это выглядит так же из
> сценария содержимого или страницы расширения.

из-за этой путаницы начинаешь теряться, где тут принимающая сторона...

Для начала удалим все дополнения в поле `permissions` файла `manifest.json`, так как в данных примерах они не понадобятся (они были добавлены от отчаяния) и переименуем `index.js` в `content.js` (так будет информативнее):

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Name",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Description",
    "icons": {
        "128": "128.png"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "page.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"],
            "css": ["index.css"],
            "run_at": "document_start"
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": []
}
```

Допустим, мы хотим прокинуть выбранный на странице текст в файл расширения. Нам нужно воспользоваться не `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` в файле `content.js`, который внедрен на целевую страницу и получает данные DOM, а `chrome.runtime.onMessage`, то есть слушать события:

content.js:

```
// получаем текст элемента и сохраняем его в локальном хранилище:
document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
    localStorage.setItem('content', JSON.stringify(target?.textContent));
})

// слушаем ответ от расширения
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(request, sender, sendResponse);
    // request - ответ от сервера
    // sender - id расширения и origin
    // после того как получен ответ от расширения отправляем данные уже
    // непосредственно ему самому
    sendResponse(JSON.stringify({ content: localStorage.getItem('content') }));
});
```

background.js

```
// отправка данных текущей вкладке
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    console.log(document); // этот документ будет ссылаться на DOM вашего расширения, то есть файла html назначенного как action: { default_popup: page.html }
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
        // response - это наш sendResponse(JSON.stringify({ content: localStorage.getItem('content') })); с предыдущего шага. Изменяем контент в DOM  расширения
        document.body.textContent = response;
        // а {greeting: "hello"} - это наш request (ответ от сервера) с предыдущего шага
    });
});
```

*Не забудьте подключить файл background.js в ваш html файд расширения используя обычный тег script.*

В моем случае нужно нажать на иконку расширения и скрипт `background.js` инициирует событие `sendMessage` и отправит данные с расширения на целевую страницу, где `content.js` будет это событие слушать и пересылать данные обратно расширению. Не наоборот, как могло показаться.

И наоборот, если нам нужно получить данные с расширения, мы должны не слушать их на целевой странице, а отправлять:

content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('Data for extension', function (msg) {
    console.log(msg); // data from extension
});
```

В расширении мы их слушаем

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(request, sender, sendResponse);
    sendResponse(`From backend: ${request}`); // это будет отправлено на целевую страницу
});
```

Имейте в виду в `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` файла `background.js` последнего примера не будет ни `window`, ни `document`. При попытке обратиться к ним вы получите: **Error in event handler: ReferenceError: window is not defined**. У расширения своя консоль. Нужно кликнуть по иконке и на всплывающем окне нажать ПКМ - исследовать. Все данные, которые приходят или логинятся в расширении будут видны там.

Ненавижу это API. Надеюсь я смог кому то помочь этим постом.

P.S. Я не использовал [полифил](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill)
P.S.S [Дока](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/) , [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/What_are_WebExtensions)